# How do i remove the <soapenv:Envelope> <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body> tags from getting generated from my wsdl?

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsdl, java2wsdl

I need to generate a soap request like the below one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns:ns2="http://www.xyz" xmlns="thsss.738.syhd.738">
    <Customer>
       <Group>
            <Message>Something</Message>
       </Group>
    </Customer>
</Document>
```

But the request getting generated is as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://eygyjdg.dbajshb/" xmlns:thss="thsss.738.syhd.738" xmlns:xyz="http://www.xyz">
   <soapenv:Header/>

   <soapenv:Body>
      <Document>
         <Customer>
            <Group>
               <Message>Something</Message>
            </Group>
        </Customer>
</Document>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Hence i get a *namespace on the "Document" element, is not a valid SOAP version*
Can you please tell me how to go about this.

Comment: Can you provide some more information - are you using java2wsdl to generate a WSDL based on existing java classes? If so, provide an example of how you are running the command.

Comment: Yes, using webservice and xmlelement annotations

Comment: Can you post the java2wsdl command you are running including any options you are passing.